# memsql aggregator fail - how to recover the cluster

Tags: singlestore

I have a memsql cluster with 4 child aggregators, 30 leaves and one master that failed. At this point i can't recover the master no matter what i am going to do. That instance is gone.  I have promoted one of the child aggregators to master.

Once i connect to memsql and i run show databases;   shoe leaves/aggregators ... everything is in place. However how do i manage to convert this child into a master?  I mean , on the web UI the master appears  running  a freshly start cluster with zero leaves. Also i can't see any master folder created on the child aggregator that was promoted.

So my question is where am i going from here? For example if i want to restart the entire cluster how am i going to do it given the fact that from the child promoted node i get memsql-ops memsql-list
No MemSQL nodes were found  ?

How will i performa the typical operations   - update, restart?

Comment: So, connecting to the aggregator you promoted and running SHOW AGGREGATORs and SHOW LEAVES shows all the leaves and aggregators in your cluster, but the memsql-ops dashboard doesn't show this information correctly?

Comment: Exactly. Shows an empty list.

Comment: Same as : memsql-ops memsql-list    >>  No MemSQL nodes were found

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have successfully promoted a child aggregator to master in the MemSQL cluster, but MemSQL Ops has lost all the cluster information because the Ops primary agent - which by default was on the same host as the Master Aggregator - is gone.

I'm not sure about your situation - did you promote a new Ops primary agent? - but in general, if you have a functioning MemSQL cluster and MemSQL Ops on all the nodes of the cluster, but Ops is not monitoring MemSQL (i.e. memsql-ops memsql-list is empty), you would run memsql-ops memsql-monitor for each MemSQL node to add them into Ops monitoring.

EDIT: answer was you haven't promoted a new Ops primary agent yet. In that case, here is what you should need to do.

- Run memsql-ops unfollow on every node except the old primary
- Choose a node to be the new primary - e.g. the new Master Aggregator.
- Run memsql-ops follow -h NEW_PRIMARY_HOSTNAME on every node except the new primary
- Run memsql-ops monitor -h NEW_MASTER_AGGREGATOR

Comment: memsql-ops memsql-monitor    >>
Could not reach primary agent. Verify primary agent is online and reachable or run memsql-ops unfollow --force to remove this agent from the topology.

Comment: this leaf i assume it is still following the ex master as a primary agent (?)

Comment: Ok, so I guess you did not promote a new primary agent. Which node are you looking at the Ops web ui on? Is it still the original Master Aggregator node? I'll add instructions to promote a new Ops primary above for better formatting.

Comment: No , the original master aggregator node was a faulty AWS instance that was terminated . I was looking at the new master (ex  child aggregator ) . Since that one was promoted as the new master i was assuming that entire old master functionality is going to be sent to the new master.

Comment: There are two separate "master" concepts - the MemSQL cluster itself has the Master Aggregator, and separately MemSQL Ops has a Primary Agent. It looks like you transferred the former by promoting a child aggregator, but not the latter.

Comment: Thank you Jack, that makes a lot of sense.What i did was to promote the new master (ex child) as primary agent and ask the leaves and other aggregators to stop following the dead master node and start following this new master.  These steps update the memsl-ops agent-list output with the correct master and followers  entries. After that,running memsql-ops monitor introduces the other nodes back in the desires hierarchy (memsql-list finally shows the correct output).

Comment: Also, what saved me from downtime all this time was replication. I quickly set up a clone cluster and replicated from this cluster to the new one. Then, once replication was finished, i've stopped it and the slave cluster became master and all data started being transferred to it.

Comment: Good to hear. For the Ops changes, were the instructions above what you did, or did you have to do something else?